# Integrate value from JavaScript in HTML form to post it in php

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm creating a form in which there are 2 variables namely 'vkey' and 'gene+varient' which is obtained by JS code.
The value is displayed correctly in the html form, just that I cant POST this value when I submit the form.
How can I POST the 2 mentioned values when I submit the form?

```
<form action="acmg_controller.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <p>
        Source:
        <select name="source">
            <option value="pubmed">PubMed</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
        </select>
        PMID:
        <input type="text" name = "pmid" style="width: 80px"> <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="vkey" id="pvkey">
        vkey:
        <script>
            var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
            var temVkey = hashParams[2].split('=');
            var vkey = temVkey[1];
            document.write(vkey);
        </script> <br>
        gene+varient
        <input type="hidden" name="genevar">
        <script>
            var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
            var temvarient = hashParams[1].split('=');
            var varient = temvarient[1];
            var hashParams_ = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
            var temgene = hashParams_[0].split('=');
            var gene = temgene[1];
            document.write(gene+' '+varient);
        </script> <br>
    </p>        
    <label>Summary:</label> <br>
    <textarea style = "width: -webkit-fill-available;height: 400px" name="text"> 
    </textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Assign the values to hidden inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to set the variables equal to the value in your hidden fields, like:

`document.getElementById('pvkey').value = vkey;`

Should give you:

```
<form action="acmg_controller.php" method="POST" target="_blank">
    <p>
        Source:
        <select name="source">
            <option value="pubmed">PubMed</option>
            <option value="other">other</option>
        </select>
        PMID:
        <input type="text" name = "pmid" style="width: 80px"> <br>
        <input type="hidden" name="vkey" id="pvkey">
        vkey:
        <script>
            var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
            var temVkey = hashParams[2].split('=');
            var vkey = temVkey[1];
            document.write(vkey);
            document.getElementById('pvkey').value = vkey;
        </script> <br>
        gene+varient
        <input type="hidden" name="genevar" id="genevar">
        <script>
            var hashParams = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
            var temvarient = hashParams[1].split('=');
            var varient = temvarient[1];
            var hashParams_ = window.location.hash.substr(1).split('&');
            var temgene = hashParams_[0].split('=');
            var gene = temgene[1];
            document.write(gene+' '+varient);
            document.getElementById('genevar').value = gene+' '+varient;
        </script> <br>
    </p>        
    <label>Summary:</label> <br>
    <textarea style = "width: -webkit-fill-available;height: 400px" name="text"> 
    </textarea> <br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```